# Hide the logon screen windows 10 IOT

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy

I want my system to boot straight into an application with no other UI elements.

I have set the system to boot using the Custom User Interface and boot straight into the application but during the login process it shows the user name, picture, loading "dots" and background.

Is there any way to just have this as a blank screen?

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with windows 10 IoT, but the usual method for skipping
the login screen and to log directly on boot into a user account is
to enter Control Panel -> User Accounts, click on your user account to select it
and uncheck the box labeled “Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer”.

You’ll be prompted to enter the user account’s password - enter the password
and click OK.

---

If this option does not exist in Windows Iot, here is how to do the same
via the registry (regedit) :

- Navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
- Enter `1` as the value of `AutoAdminLogon`
- Enter the computer name (or domain) as the value of `DefaultDomainName`
- Enter the account name as the value of `DefaultUserName`
- Enter the account's password as the value of `DefaultPassword`

More info can be found [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3539-sign-user-account-automatically-windows-10-startup.html#option2).

---

To disable the Windows 10 Welcome Screen in Group Policy Editor :

- Run `gpedit.ms`
- Navigate to: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon
- Double-click the “Do not display the Getting Started welcome screen at logon”
- Choose “Disable”
- Click OK

Next time you restart the computer, your computer will automatically bypass the Windows 10 login screen.

Comment: I was intrigued by this answer, having never encountered this setting, but I can't find it in Win10 Pro 1709. Does it need a particular configuration to enable it?

Comment: IoT might miss this option. I added a registry method above.

Comment: This will successfully autologon an account, but the logon welcome screens will continue to be visible.

Comment: I use a SysInternals utility [Autologon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/autologon) which makes the registry changes without needing the registry editor, but like @TwistyImpersonator I don't think this answers the question completely.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: I added above what I believe is the missing piece.

Comment: thanks for the help, the auto admin is working fine but when the first boot happens i still see the user name and the spinning dots. whats stranger is if i do a warm reboot i also briefly see the clock.
Is there by any chance a way to set the font colour of the lock screen to black so i can at lease hide it?

Comment: This [link](https://techhelpkb.com/change-the-windows-10-lock-screen-to-a-solid-color/) may do it.

Comment: Your second tip there (to disable the Welcome screen) doesn't seem to work - and when I read the text at the side of this option, it says that it applies to Windows 2000 Professional only.

Comment: @colmde: The comment  wasn't updated since Windows 2000, but this policy continued working long afterward, but it may be disabled because of other settings.

Comment: @harrymc - Do you know what other settings might prevent this from working?

Comment: @colmde: No, too many changes in Windows 10 to keep track.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Processes page on the IoT Utilities page and type these commands. 
It should disable the Windows logo.

1. `bcdedit /set quietboot on`
2. `bcdedit /set bootux Disabled`
3. `bcdedit /set bootuxdisabled on`

Comment: Although this didn't disable the welcome screen, it did disable the loading screen that shows before the welcome screen, so the welcome screen seems less jarring. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was the only setting that worked for me to visually hide the welcome screen on Windows 10:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Embedded\EmbeddedLogon" /v "HideAutoLogonUI" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

I used this setting together with the AutoAdminLogon from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1267935).

More information about this registry key can be found on MSDN:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-embedded-embeddedlogon