# How to totally remove the Windows 10 login screen?

Tags: windows-10, boot, login, kiosk

I'd like to have the most "Unbranded boot" as possible on Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise.

I have read a few similar questions and I have already done the following steps:

- Enabled user Auto login (no password asked) (I set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device` to 1 and then I could uncheck *"Users must enter a user name ..."* and set "Auto login" after doing `cmd` > `control userpasswords2`.
- "Lock screen settings" > Background > image, and I removed as many options as I could in this dialog box
- Remove Lock Screen in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization\NoLockScreen` : 1
- gpedit.msc > Administrative templates > "Do not display the lock screen"
- I have even replaced `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` by my own app, you can try with `notepad.exe`
- Start menu > "Turn Windows Features On and Off" > Device Lockdown > Shell Launcher, Unbranded boot, Custom logon

It works: on boot, the user automatically logs in. But still, this loading screen is still displayed during ~ 0.5 to 1 second:

[image]

**How to completely remove this screen?**

---

Here is a possible option but I am not sure if it works for Win 10 Pro or Enterprise: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-embedded-embeddedlogon-animationdisabled. I do not know what to do with this XML file, where to load it, in which Windows configuration menu.

---

Edit: here is the full boot sequence - which ones are configurable from Windows? Obviously A is not, and C and D are configurable from Windows, but what about B?

Screen A:

[image]

Screen B:

[image]

Screen C:

[image]

Screen D:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Custom Logon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/custom-logon)
only applies when preparing a Windows installation image, meaning that
you would need to reinstall Windows from scratch using the Windows image
that you have created.

The
[link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-embedded-embeddedlogon-animationdisabled)
in your post relates only to disabling animation on the
logon screen, and it also belongs to Custom Logon.

A running system cannot be modified this way and the XML that you have
found is part of the input used for creating the custom image,
and cannot be used for the running system.

You may for your running system :

- **Disguise your name in the logon screen** by in
  *Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users*,
  double-click your account and in the General tab set your Full name to
  any text message.
- **Change the displayed image** in *Settings  > Accounts > Your info*.

---

**Analysis of the Custom Logon feature of Windows Enterprise**

If you have the Windows Enterprise version, you may enable
[Custom Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/customize/custom-logon)
in *Control Panel > Turn Windows features on or off* and
enable the following registry items under
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Embedded\EmbeddedLogon`.

[image]

Setting
[BrandingNeutral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-embedded-embeddedlogon-brandingneutral)
as follows:

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Disables all Welcome screen UI elements. |
| 2 | Disables the **Power** button. |
| 4 | Disables the **Language** button. |
| 8 | Disables the **Ease of access** button. |
| 16 | Disables the **Switch user** button. |
| 32 | Disables the blocked shutdown resolver (BSDR) screen so that restarting or shutting down the system causes the OS to immediately force close any applications that are blocking system shut down. No UI is displayed and users are not given a chance to cancel the shutdown process. This can result in a loss of data if any open applications have unsaved data. |

You may further set
[HideAutoLogonUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-embedded-embeddedlogon-hideautologonui)
to the value of `1` to hide the Welcome screen.
Another item you may set is `HideFirstLogonAnimation`.

I have tried the above settings, and this suppresses almost all
of the loading screen, except for the turning circle.

**Just to remark that you will get the exact same experience by
setting the user image and display-name to empty**
without the need to have Windows Enterprise.

Comment: Thank you Harry! `Custom Logon only applies when preparing a Windows installation image, meaning that you would need to reinstall Windows from scratch using the Windows image that you have created.`: there surely is a way to "test" if the image we are preparing has the right custom logon, how to test this? I cannot imagine that we have to redo *a full install from scratch* each time we do a test to see if the "Custom Logon" features have been correctly set. Is that right? Thanks!

Comment: New Windows image can only be used to create Windows boot media, cannot be applied to the running system. A dangerous idea is to use the new image to do an [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), so as to "upgrade" the existing system to the new one. But I suggest taking very strong backup measures of your disk before going this way. Changing the text and the image, to even empty ones, might be just as good. In all cases, during these 2 seconds an empty screen might be worse than something.

Comment: You can easily test that with your old computer or with VMWare/HyperV

Comment: @basj That is what virtual machines are for.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer @harrymc but I'm specifically looking to remove [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLRVH.png) which appears before logon.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is not correct. Read the first article you linked, where it says: `"If Windows has already been installed and you are applying a provisioning package to configure Custom Logon, you must first turn on Custom Logon in order for a provisioning package to be successfully applied.
The Custom Logon feature is available in the Control Panel."` So you CAN apply custom logon to a running system, in a well-documented way.

Comment: @Basj: I have added above my test of the Custom Logon option available in Windows Enterprise, and can say that it gives exactly the same results as in my answer by hiding image and user display-name (without the need for Enterprise). I think my answer was correct to start with, and is the maximum you may achieve in a running system.

Comment: Thank you very much @harrymc for the update of the answer, I'll try this as soon as possible!

Comment: PS @harrymc: I give the bounty to 1NN because he brought new information (the fact that we can modify these settings in Registry) but both your answers are helpful!

Comment: These registry settings are only available in Windows Enterprise once the Custom Logon feature is enabled, and can also be done via other less-esoteric and more modern methods. From the registry key name, I guess that they are a remnant of some old Windows Embedded version.

Comment: @Basj: This is covered in my answer. If it doesn't work for you, better post a separate question.

Comment: @Basj: Please create a separate question, specifying your Windows version and the problem.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](https://www.tenforums.com/user-accounts-family-safety/191760-autologon-without-display-username.html), once [custom logon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/custom-logon) is properly configured, you get a new key in your registry:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Embedded\EmbeddedLogon
```

Edit the DWORD `HideAutoLoginUI` and set its value to `1`.

This should result in a blank screen until the desktop appears.

Additionally, you might want or need to configure [unbranded boot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/unbranded-boot) to hide any windows logo.

**EDIT**:
There is a [related Windows documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-embedded-embeddedlogon-hideautologonui) which implicitly confirms you'll need to have custom logon configured for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for unbranded, you can also change the boot logo with a utility such as hack bgrt.

while it might be dificult to remove the login loafing screen, you could reasearch a solution that blocks all monitor output while the computer is starting windows, meaning you cannot see a login screen.
i am unsure if there is a simple software way to do this but if you plug a dummy display into a different video port and set it as the primary in windows, login information such as the loading screen may be blocked. This works under windows 7 and 10 with a seccond display however I am unsure if a dummy will produce the desired effect.
you could then produce a script to modify the monitor settings so the actual display is set to primary allowing programs to open in the correct display.

EDIT: here are some links
an example of dummy screen adapters: https://www.amazon.co.uk/EASYDIY-Displayport-Emulator-Headless-4096x2160/dp/B079FW3DCP

hackbgrt:
https://github.com/Metabolix/HackBGRT

Answer (score 1):

As a summary, thanks to the great other answers + this answer from [Hide the logon screen windows 10 IOT](https://superuser.com/questions/1267931/hide-the-logon-screen-windows-10-iot/1409454#1409454), here is what I noticed about Screens A, B, C, D of the full boot sequence (see screenshots at the end of my question):

- Screen A is out of reach from Windows
- Screen C can be removed with:

  ```
  bcdedit /set quietboot on
  bcdedit /set bootux Disabled
  bcdedit /set bootuxdisabled on
  ```
- Screen D can be removed with `Custom Logon` feature turned on (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zvBG.jpg), this step is really necessary, only doing the next regedit step is not enough) and the DWORD key (create it if necessary)

  ```
  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Embedded\EmbeddedLogon\HideAutoLoginUI
  ```

  set to `1`.

About Screen B (the only difference with Screen C is that there is just the logo, and no animated dots), I suspect it's already part of the Windows boot sequence (even if there is the BIOS logo - probably Windows took this logo during install). I don't know how to remove this.