# Remove a specific logon Windows screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, login

I'm trying, on Windows 10 Pro, to prevent [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTIMf.jpg) to appear.

This question is specifically about precisions about the answer [How to totally remove the Windows 10 login screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1733545/how-to-totally-remove-the-windows-10-login-screen/1784695#1784695), thus this [new question](https://superuser.com/questions/1733545/how-to-totally-remove-the-windows-10-login-screen/1784695#comment2874190_1784695).

This answer states:

> Disguise your name in the logon screen by in Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users, double-click your account and in the General tab set your Full name to **any text message**.

> exact same experience by setting the user image and **display-name to empty**

Follwing this answer:

- I tried both options:

  - setting the "Full name" to some non-empty text like `"test"` ([this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTIMf.jpg) still appears after next reboot),
  - and to an empty text (idem)
- I tried to change the account image, as advised in the answer (*"Change the displayed image in Settings > Accounts > Your info"*), but I can only use "camera" or "browse to a new file". Thus I can only customize the account image, but not **remove** the current image.

Thus I cannot prevent [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTIMf.jpg) to appear.

NB: This question is specifically about this method:

> **Just to remark that you will get the exact same experience by setting the user image and display-name to empty** without the need to have Windows Enterprise.

and not about other methods (so it is not a duplicate).

Comment: Strange, when I wrote that answer I tested everything and it all worked. A Windows update might have nixed this method since when I wrote it, or your situation is different. Questions: What is your exact Windows 10 version? Your account is named "admin", is that a local or Microsoft account?

Comment: @harrymc I tested on two computers with different versions of Windows 10 Pro (I'll tell you which tomorrow). Which Window 10 Pro version did you use? Just to be sure: Did you mean 1) "Full name" set to empty string ? 2) Full name set to any *non-empty* text ?  3) Use any image ? 4) Or "remove the image"  ?

Comment: I think I set the full name to one space/blank.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. I tried both without success. Last question: did [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTIMf.jpg) totally disappear, or was it still displayed, but with an empty text and empty image (but still the round circle with the silhouette icon)?

Comment: Still displayed with empty both.

Comment: @harrymc If it is "still displayed", then I did not understand [your answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1733545/how-to-totally-remove-the-windows-10-login-screen/1784695#1784695): "You will get the exact same experience by setting the user image and display-name to empty without the need to have Windows Enterprise". With Enterprise you can totally prevent [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTIMf.jpg) to appear - with your solution the screen is still displayed, but with blank text. So it's not the exact same experience - do you agree if I modify your answer?

Comment: As I pointed in that answer and comments, you can reduce this screen to basically just a spinning wheel, but you can't avoid the processing that's done behind it. Totally getting rid of everything will result in a blank screen for the duration, so a more negative experience for the user.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. Did you mean : the spinning wheel + also the round white circle (+ also the silhouette icon inside the circle) in https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTIMf.jpg?

Comment: Yes, I meant the entire animation that's supposed to reassure the user that something is still working. A long blank screen may cause the user to push the power button.